# Is there better performance listing out multiple Components versus dynamically generating them?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to render multiple Views based on JSON. I'm not doing a list, but creating visual full size screens with each View.  I have here three different methods I'm considering to render multiple components (first two are dynamic, last one is explicit).

- If I already know what I want to render, is doing a `.map` actually hurting my performance?

The reason I want to use it is because it lets us configure the UI with JSON for future features.

Tangent: I have read that placing the loop function outside of the `render()` is better, but doesn't say how (seems syntactically the same).

---

```
    // Inline Render - most commonly seen example
    class MyParentView extends React.Component {

        render() {
            let json = [{
                view: 1
            }, {
                view: 2
            }, {
                view: 3
            }];

            let views = json.map((view, i) => {
                return <View key={i} parentProps={...this.props}>{view.i}</View>
            });

            return <View>{views}</View>

        }
    }

    // Outside function render
    class MyParentView extends React.Component {

        _makeViews = () => {
            let json = [{
                view: 1
            }, {
                view: 2
            }, {
                view: 3
            }];
            return json.map((view, i) => {
                return <View key={i} parentProps={...this.props}>{view.i}</View>
            });
        }

        render() {
            return <View>{this._makeViews()}</View>
        }
    }

    // Explicit render
    class MyParentView extends React.Component {

        render() {
            return <View>
                <View key={1} parentProps={...this.props}>{1}</View>
                <View key={2} parentProps={...this.props}>{2}</View>
                <View key={3} parentProps={...this.props}>{3}</View>
            </View>
        }
    }
```

Comment: This answer will satisfy your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52020636/2138752